# Applying margin to checkbox input and not its label

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to adjust a checkbox-input's position, by applying a margin-top without effecting its label. But it seems the margin-top css applied only to the input, moves its label along with it as well.

Is there a way I may just apply the style to input alone, and not its label?

Here's the html:

```
<dd id="rr-element">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rr-1" name="rr[]" />
  <label for="rr-1">
    Value 1
  </label>
</dd>
```

Here's the css:

```
dd input {
  margin-top:15px;
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T86h8/455/)

Comment: Hint 1: What happens to the line when you move your `<input>`? Hint 2: `dd::first-line{background-color:red;}`.

Comment: @Zeta What do you mean by moving the <input>? Sorry didn't get you..

Comment: Hints above apply to both, the input and its label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this, use `top` instead of `margin-top` and add `position:relative;` to input.

```
dd input{
    position:relative;
    top:15px;
}
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T86h8/481/

Comment: That worked just fine! I think not specifying the position made the CSS consider both input and its label for margin alignment.
Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Akul Von Itram can you please explain me the concept behind your solution?

Comment: `position: relative` will layout an element relative to itself. In other words, the elements is laid out in normal flow, then it is removed from normal flow and offset by whatever values you have specified (top, right, bottom, left).

Comment: @AkulVonItram thank you for the explanation, really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative;` CSS to `dd input` and replace `margin-top` with `top` as following:

```
dd input {
    top: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anini/T86h8/489/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
#rr-1
{
  margin-top:15px !important; 
}
```

Comment: A suggestion to avoid the use of !important for CSS, since it leads to further more troubles than solving an issue.
[See Here](http://james.padolsey.com/css/dont-use-important/)